# How can I align the text of a date input to the left on iOS 15?

Tags: css, input, text-align, ios15

On iOS 15, `text-align: left;` doesn't seem to have an effect on `<input type="date" />`. The text stays centered when it doesn't completely fill the box. How can I make sure it is aligned to the left using CSS?

Here's a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-nuv8zt?file=styles.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styling the date-and-time-value pseudoelement works for me.

```
input::-webkit-date-and-time-value {
    text-align: left;
}
```